# Did any Jews have the same canon as Jesus during the time of Christ and did the early church ever quote from it?

Tags: early-church, old-testament, judaism, deuterocanonical-books

Orthodox Christians have a much larger canon than both Roman Catholic and Protestant Christians, this includes books such as 3 Maccabees.  During the time of Jesus there were different sects of Jews.  Did any Jewish sect have the same canon as the Orthodox Christians?  Did any of the Early Church Fathers quote from the orthodox canon?

Comment: Now I'm invested in the question whether there was such a thing as a canon among Jews at that time. If there was, that would certainly have had an impact on the christian canon.

Comment: [Here's a lengthy list](https://github.com/HistoricalChristianFaith/Argument-Analysis/blob/master/arguments/ecf_quote_deut.md) of Early Church Father quotations from the Catholic Deuterocanonical books (that Orthodox accept, but Protestants reject) explicitly as scripture.

Answer (score 1):

About 3 Maccabees in particular, here is what I have learned and assume applies to other books as well:

The book was not included in the Hebrew scriptures, but was included in the greek Septuagint. The Septuagint ended up being the basis for the Old Testament of Christians.

This leads me to the conclusion that probably, in Judea, Jews did for the most part not use 3 Maccabees or see it as authoritative, but hellenistic Jews might have.

Given all that, it seems unlikely the apostles would have cited it, but somewhat more likely for early church leaders using the Septuagint.

However, Wikipedia has this to say about 3 Maccabees:

> 3 Maccabees was not influential. No Jewish writers of the ancient era
> appear to reference it or be familiar with it, even those who wrote in
> Greek. The book was not translated into the Latin Vulgate, hence the
> Western Church's rejection of including it even as a member of the
> deuterocanonical books. While the book was kept in the Greek-speaking
> Eastern Church's scripture, it is **only very rarely referenced or
> alluded to**.[22][3] Theodoret briefly summarizes 3 Maccabees in one of
> his writings, but this is the rare exception; the work had little
> influence on Christianity.[3] 3 Maccabees is included in the
> deuterocanon of the Eastern Orthodox Church and some Oriental Orthodox
> Churches: the Armenian Apostolic Church, the Syriac Orthodox Church,
> and the Assyrian Church of the East. The Apostolic Canons approved by
> the Eastern Church's Council in Trullo in 692 verified 1, 2, and 3
> Maccabees were deuterocanonical, but the Council was rejected by the
> Western Church's Pope Sergius I.